# React Native onPress TouchableHighlights individually?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I just wanted to create a simple TicTacToe game. For that, I need 9 buttons. I created a basic layout using Views surrounded by TouchableHighlights to make them clickable.

If I'm clicking on Button, only that button should change it's color, but currently all buttons change the color at the same.
Does anybody got an idea how to fix this?

I don't know how to handle the state individually for every TouchableHighlight.

Really appreciate all help.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
    Dimensions,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

var screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
screenWidth-=36;
var screenHeigth = Dimensions.get('window').height;

let randomHex = () => {
  let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  let color = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

export default class randomBackground extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      backgroundColor: '#f5aef5'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5', flex: 1}}>

          <Text style={{color:'black', alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 100, marginTop: 60}}>TicTacToe</Text>

          <View style={styles.outercardview}>

            {/* row 1 */}
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>

              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({backgroundColor: randomHex()})}  underlayColor="white" style={{ height: screenWidth/3, width: screenWidth/3, borderRadius: 9, margin: 3, backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor}}>
                <View>

                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>

              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() =>this.setState({backgroundColor: randomHex()})} underlayColor="white" style={{ height: screenWidth/3, width: screenWidth/3, borderRadius: 9, margin: 3, backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor}}>
                <View>

                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>

              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({backgroundColor: randomHex()})} underlayColor="white" style={{ height: screenWidth/3, width: screenWidth/3, borderRadius: 9, margin: 3, backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor}}>
                <View>

                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>

            </View>

        </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  outercardview: {
    marginTop: (screenHeigth/2)-(screenWidth/2)-140,
    marginBottom: 20,
    marginRight: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height:screenWidth,

    shadowOffset: {
      width: 2,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowColor: 'grey',
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
  }
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('randomBackground', () => randomBackground);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
    Dimensions,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

var screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
screenWidth-=36;
var screenHeigth = Dimensions.get('window').height;

let randomHex = () => {
  let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  let color = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

export default class randomBackground extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      backgroundColor1: '#f5aef5',
      backgroundColor2: '#f5aef5',
      backgroundColor3: '#f5aef5'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5', flex: 1}}>

          <Text style={{color:'black', alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 100, marginTop: 60}}>TicTacToe</Text>

          <View style={styles.outercardview}>

            {/* row 1 */}
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>

              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({backgroundColor1: randomHex()})}  underlayColor="white" style={{ height: screenWidth/3, width: screenWidth/3, borderRadius: 9, margin: 3, backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor1}}>
                <View>

                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>

              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() =>this.setState({backgroundColor2: randomHex()})} underlayColor="white" style={{ height: screenWidth/3, width: screenWidth/3, borderRadius: 9, margin: 3, backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor2}}>
                <View>

                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>

              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({backgroundColor3: randomHex()})} underlayColor="white" style={{ height: screenWidth/3, width: screenWidth/3, borderRadius: 9, margin: 3, backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor3}}>
                <View>

                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>

            </View>

        </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  outercardview: {
    marginTop: (screenHeigth/2)-(screenWidth/2)-140,
    marginBottom: 20,
    marginRight: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height:screenWidth,

    shadowOffset: {
      width: 2,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowColor: 'grey',
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
  }
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('randomBackground', () => randomBackground);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the `backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor` for all the buttons they are of same color what you can do is maintain a variable which holds the present index/id of the button you pressed and set the background color as  `backgroundColor: this.state.activeButton===buttonid ?this.state.backgroundColor:''`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how can I access the activeButton variable? I really got no idea how to access the current button to change it's values.